# List of Shema words

Tags: shema, tractate-brachot

Does anyone have a list of the words in Shema that are easy to mess up on, in that the last letter of the first word is the first letter of the next one? For instance, על לבבך and ואבדתם מהרה. The mishna isn’t Berachot mentions to articulate phrases like these so that you don’t accidentally combine them since the letters are the same. So does anyone have a list of all the instances of these?

Comment: Many siddurim mark them with a line between the words.

Comment: I think the artscroll siddurs put lines in between words like that

Comment: @ezra There are other types of errors, like overemphasizing the ז in תזכרו.

Comment: They are listed in the Talmud right there https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86753/759

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Shulchan Aruch Siman 61 (15-21) for list of words requiring careful recitation.