How could the words עשב בשדך run together?
Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 61:20 states:

One should put a gap between a word whose beginning [letter] is like
the end [letter] of its predecessor, for example: "b'chol l'vav'kha",
"al l'vav'khem", "eisev b'sad'kha", "v'avdem m'heira", "hakanaf
p'til", "etkhem meieretz"

How could עשב בשדך (or for that matter הכנף פתיל) run together? Although the two adjacent letters are consecutive, one is חזק\דגוש, so they represent completely different phonemes. Were these letters pronounced differently in the past? Do any commentators address this question? Where is the source of these examples?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86753/759

Many Mizrahim pronounce both as /b/.

The source for the Shulchan Aruch's examples is the statement of Rava recorded in Berachot 15b. So what we really need to know is how these consonants were pronounced in fourth century Mesopotamia.
R. Shimon b. Tzemach Duran writes in Magen Avot vol. III p. 54:

הבי"ת הרפה הוגים אותה ... בדיבוק שפתיים כמו הדגושה בדגש רפה במעט שינוי ברפיון יותר ... שאי אפשר שתהא הגיית הבי"ת כהגיית הוי"ו בשום פנים ולא היתה כן הגייתנו בהיותנו בארצנו ויורה זה מה שאמרו בק"ש שיניח ריוח בין הדבקים ומנו שם כמו עשב בשדך יראה כי הגיית בי"ת עשב כהגיית בי"ת בשדך שהיא דגושה
The "weak" bet is pronounced ... with the lips together, in the same way as the "stressed" bet (i.e. with a dagesh kal), with a small change in that they are slightly looser... It cannot in any way be that it is pronounced like a vav, and that was not our pronunciation when we were in our land. This is proven from what is said regarding keriat shema, that one leaves a gap between similar-sounding letters, using as an example עשב בשדך. It appears the the pronunciation of bet in עשב is similar to its pronunciation in בשדך, where it is "stressed".

It's interesting to note that Rambam does not provide עשב בשדך as an example in Hilchot Keriat Shema 2:9. Perhaps in his time and place, the phonemes were sufficiently far apart that he was not concerned about running the two together.
